# How get larger amount of data from Stack Exchange API?

Tags: python, json, stackexchange-api

The Stack Exchange API returns only 30 items per request. I used a `for` loop to call the stack Exchange API like given below to get 4500 records.

```
import requests
complete_data=[]
for i in range (150):
    response = requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow")
    newData=json.loads(response.text)
    for item in newData['items']:
        complete_data.append(item)
```

But while analyzing the questions I got from the API, there was same data sets which was received 150 times. So I have received same data set for each data request in the code. I need to have near 5000 records to analyze data. Can anyone show me what changes should I do in my code?

Comment: This question belongs on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Can I have a link for that?

Comment: Add a `&pagesize=100` parameter (max, will return 100 items). Default is 30, as you realized and minimum is 1. In addition, you should also send a `&page=` parameter which should be equal to `i+1`. You are fetching the same page 150 times, currently! (Note: for 4.5k questions, you need `for i in range (45)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually fetching 30 items per request and the same page (the first one). Define [pagesize (max 100, min 1) and page (`i + 1`)](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/paging) in order to solve the problem:

```
import requests
import time

complete_data=[]
for i in range (45):
    response = requests.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&pagesize=100&page=" + str(i + 1))
    newData=json.loads(response.text)
    for item in newData['items']:
        complete_data.append(item)
    print("Processed page " + str(i + 1) + ", returned " + str(response))
    time.sleep(2) # timeout not to be rate-limited
```

Notes:

- Timeout for 2 seconds added to prevent [rate-limiting](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).
- You may want to obtain an API key to increase your quota from 300 to 10000.

Comment: [The error from fetching 180+ pages has actually been fixed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338347/939282)